# Что делать - вылетает из MySQL Workbench?

Tags: html, mysql, sql

При запуске базы данных, в программе MySQL Workbench - запускается программа, и потом сразу же закрывается. Подскажите пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с этой проблемой, что делать?

```
Имя журнала:   Application
Источник:      .NET Runtime
Дата:          04.12.2018 1:53:06
Код события:   1026
Категория задачи:Отсутствует
Уровень:       Ошибка
Ключевые слова:Классический
Приложение: MySQLWorkbench.exe
Версия платформы: v4.0.30319
Описание. Процесс был завершен из-за необработанного исключения.
Сведения об исключении: System.AccessViolationException
   в <Module>.wb.WBContextUI.init_finish(wb.WBContextUI*, wb.WBOptions*)
   в MySQL.Workbench.WbContext.finished_loading(MySQL.Workbench.WbOptions)
   в MySQL.GUI.Workbench.Program.Main(System.String[])


Xml события:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-12-03T22:53:06.464792100Z" />
    <EventRecordID>18914</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-MSTKF8S</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Приложение: MySQLWorkbench.exe
Версия платформы: v4.0.30319
Описание. Процесс был завершен из-за необработанного исключения.
Сведения об исключении: System.AccessViolationException
   в &lt;Module&gt;.wb.WBContextUI.init_finish(wb.WBContextUI*, wb.WBOptions*)
   в MySQL.Workbench.WbContext.finished_loading(MySQL.Workbench.WbOptions)
   в MySQL.GUI.Workbench.Program.Main(System.String[])

</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

И ВТОРАЯ ОШИБКА:

```
Имя журнала:   Application
Источник:      Application Error
Дата:          04.12.2018 1:53:06
Код события:   1000
Категория задачи:(100)
Уровень:       Ошибка
Ключевые слова:Классический
Пользователь:  Н/Д
Компьютер:     DESKTOP-MSTKF8S
Описание:
Имя сбойного приложения: MySQLWorkbench.exe, версия: 8.0.11.0, метка времени: 0x5aca6da1
Имя сбойного модуля: grt.dll, версия: 0.0.0.0, метка времени: 0x5aca69fa
Код исключения: 0xc0000005
Смещение ошибки: 0x0000000000007f99
Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x2b6c
Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d48b5aef8c7c1d
Путь сбойного приложения: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\MySQLWorkbench.exe
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\grt.dll
Идентификатор отчета: dc140ae4-7e89-4d26-8445-3ee2622d4ea8
Полное имя сбойного пакета: 
Код приложения, связанного со сбойным пакетом: 
Xml события:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-12-03T22:53:06.660199900Z" />
    <EventRecordID>18915</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-MSTKF8S</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>MySQLWorkbench.exe</Data>
    <Data>8.0.11.0</Data>
    <Data>5aca6da1</Data>
    <Data>grt.dll</Data>
    <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>5aca69fa</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>0000000000007f99</Data>
    <Data>2b6c</Data>
    <Data>01d48b5aef8c7c1d</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\MySQLWorkbench.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\grt.dll</Data>
    <Data>dc140ae4-7e89-4d26-8445-3ee2622d4ea8</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Читать логи для начала, а уже потом, с данными из логов, приходить сюда с вопросами, если самостоятельно разобраться не выйдет.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, где я могу прочитать эти данные?

Comment: Смотря какая ОС. Для Windows - в "просмотре событий"

Comment: Спасибо. Выдаёт вот такие ошибки...

Comment: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1649117

Comment: Спасибо. Пробую.